# Azure Data Factory - copy unknown number of files into corresponding tables

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to copy unknown number of files into db tables.
Lets say I have two files named 1 and 2 and I want to copy them to it's tables named A and B.

1 - A
2 - B

I have done this by creating mapping table

```
|SourceFileName|TargetTableName|
|1             |A              |
|2             |B              |
```

I'm able to complete that task when both files are present but sometimes only one file will be there. In that case my ForEach loop gets failed and I want it to still pass and go to next task.
Now I have Get Metadata which is passing Childitems to ForEach loop, and inside that loop I have a Lookup based on mapping table and Copy activity based on that lookup @activity('lookup').output.value[0].TargetTableName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **parameterize** the **lookup query** to get a single table name based on the source file and pass the output of lookup to copy activity to load data.

This will loop the `Foreach` activity based on the number of Input files (1 or more) from the `Get Metadata` output.

**Mapping table (lookup table):**

[image]

Output of **Get Metadata** activity:

[image]

- In **Foreach** loop -->`Lookup` activity, **parameterize** the query to get the table name based on the source filename.

  ```
  @concat('SELECT top 1 [TableName] FROM [dbo].[MappingTable] where Filename = ''', string(item().name), '''')
  ```

[image]

**Output of Lookup activity**:

[image]

- In `Copy data` activity, pass the current **Foreach** file item as **Source**.

[image]

- In **Copy data activity Sink**, pass the Table name dynamically with the lookup activity output content.

  ```
  @activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.TableName
  ```

[image]

- The **Foreach** loop Content loops based on the **Get Metadata output** number of files.

[image]

- When more than one Input file:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you! thank you for the update.